# Change css style on a keypress. (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I want whenever user presses a certain keybind, the value of css style of that element gets changed.

```
<textarea id="check"
    v-model="text"
    v-on:keydown.ctrl.up="decreaseFont"
 >
```

I checked the decreaseFont function was called but value of font-size is not changing.

```
decreaseFont() {
      console.log("check")
      document.getElementById("check").style.fontSize--;
    }
```

Here's my CSS

```
div textarea {
  position: relative;
  font-size: $fontSize;
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  resize: none;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```

Also I want the textview to take the whole screen without the scrollbar. That's why I used 100vh as height. But I'am still getting a scrollbar.

I reseted the margin and padding of body to 0.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    text: '',
    fontSize: null
  },
  methods: {
    decreaseFont() {
      this.fontSize--;
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    var el = document.getElementById('check');
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
    this.fontSize = parseFloat(style);
  }
})
```

```css
div textarea {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  resize: none;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <textarea 
    id="check" 
    v-model="text" 
    v-on:keydown.ctrl.up="decreaseFont" 
    :style="{'font-size': fontSize + 'px'}">
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <textarea
      id="check"
      v-model="text"
      v-on:keydown.enter="decrease = decrease-1"
      :style="{'font-size': decrease+'px'}"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      text: null,
      decrease: 30
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
}
</style>

<style scoped>
div textarea {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  height: 99vh;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  resize: none;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
}
</style>
```

I created a [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-shaw-wliy1?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) so you can have a look at how it works.

---

Note that I made the font size change on the `enter` key for the demonstration purposes.